# Should I build a website magento from scratch for my online store?

Tags: create

I know Magento is an open-source e-commerce platform written in PHP with other. The software was originally developed by Varien, Inc, a US private company headquartered in Culver City, California, with assistance from volunteers. 
My friends tell me, Magento is the best open source for e-commerce in 2018. First, Magento is more reliable at medium and high speed, especially when compared with WordPress. Customers don’t have to take a lot of time for load website, and merchants also don’t have to take a lot of time to administrators their website. 
[image]
Second, Magento has required less frequent maintenance, although Magento website needs maintenance and upgrade services for business who sell their product online. It must be friendly, should be search engine friendly (SEO) and contain optimized images. Some maintenance services that Magento support merchants: optimizing Magento speed and performance, Magento theme update, Magento E-commerce analytics, Magento debugging and Magento search engine optimization. 
Third, Magento is more reliable because no battery is used. 
In addition, Magento also has many other advantages for merchants. Their customer can build a website Magento from scratch in the easiest way.
Disadvantage of Magento
Well, everything has two sides of it, besides the positive side also had the negative side, and Magento too. The first disadvantage, it has starting problem due to low cranking speed at staring. Then, it is more expensive compared to battery ignition system. And finally, it may be a possibility of misfire due to leakage because wiring carries very high voltage. 
Should choose to [build website Magento from scratch](http://bssgeek.com/services) or not?
After that information, I still haven't the way I do. If I build my website with Magento, I have to pay the fee to maintain, but I don’t have to take a lot of time to administrate or worry about many problems like security, speed, upgrade,..etc. 
So, what should I choose?

Comment: Magento is a reliable platform for online e-commerce business. But if you are not familiar with it and any other open source applications. I suggest to go with some other SAAS based e-commerce application. You no need to manage anything except paying for the service and asking for improvements.

Comment: Thanks, i don't know how many money i have to pay with SAAS?

Comment: Sorry I cannot answer it unfortunately. You need to check with such online service providers. Also it depends on your budget.